# SOLR Facet Search Results

Tags: solr, lucene

Ive got following schema.xml

- ...
- id
- book
- pages
- genre (horror,action)
- ...

Is solr able to return results like this?

genre;books;pages

horror(genre);12(books);124543(pages)

action(genre);2(books);437(pages)

As you can see i want to facet over more than one field. The only thing i got work is the facet search over genre and books. But i want to have the pages as a sum also in my results.
Is Solr able to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check for [Solr Pivot Faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets) which will provide you with hierarchy facets.
You can check if you get the pages, the summing can be done at Client side.